# The easiest way to pass the data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have `x = 65;` in a JavaScript page `/var/html/pag1.js`
and I want to pass `x` to a different page: `/var/html/user1/pageUser.js`

What's the easiest way to send a value like that?

Comment: Are these .js files being included in the same html page?

Comment: no
they are in different html pages

Comment: Why don't you give us a little more detail as to what in the world you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. In an attempt to decipher and give a good answer, I'll restate your question. I believe you are trying to 'post' a field called 'x' with value of '65' to another page. You say you have a 'page' with name 'page1.js', but that is a script and not a page. You might have a 'page1.html' that references 'page1.js' (same for page2). I'll proceed on the assumption you have 2 files:

1. page1.html
2. page1.js
3. page2.html
4. page2.js

Normally, data is passed between pages using form actions like this...

Page1.html:

```
<body>
    <form action='page2.html' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='x' value='65' />
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>
</body>
```

If you want to do this using javascript, you can should look into jquery and it's [post() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Here's an example in context...

Page1.html:

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'page2.html',
            data: { x : 65 },
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: As best as I can figure out his question, your second example is a good solution to what he's asking...